# Is there any way to get progress when training?

Tags: h2o

I made a call to H2ORandomForestEstimator.train(). Is there any way to get progress when training? I haven't found that.

I saw the source code and thought about to add a "callback" parameter to train(). How can I contribute code? There is no "issue" column for this project in github. Directly pull request?

Comment: I wrote an external program to call to H2ORandomForestEstimator.train() in Python. My program should show the progress when training, rather than running code in python notebook.

Answer (score 0):

What API/language do you use? In R, Python, and also in Flow the progress bar is enabled by default. If you disable it by `no_progress()` (in Python), you can again enable it by `show_progress()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can always just go to the H2O Flow Web UI, look up the job, and view the progress.

It’s very popular to submit a job with R or Python and monitor or cancel it in Flow.